# How can I uninstall an Add-on?

Tags: add-on, import

I asked a question yesterday about how to bring filled polylines in from AutoCAD without them coming in as joined filled shapes.  I was directed to a download site to get a new dxf importer.  I installed it as directed but now I have two dxf converters installed in Blender and they conflict so that I can't bring dxf files in at all.  How can I uninstall the old one?[image]

I suppose I could uninstall Blender and then reinstall it, but then I would have the same question.  Can I bring in polylines from AutoCAD without them linking to each other and creating a maze of linked filled shapes?

Comment: The old one looks like it is disabled, did you save user settings?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to delete the .py file. To do this on windows, go to `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\[version]\scripts`, and find the scripts location. Then delete the files.

Here in the screenshot of the user preferences (Which can be accessed via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>>*Scripts*) you can see the location of the script files that need to be removed.

[image]

Comment: NoviceInDisguise, no I did not save my user settings.  I followed the directions given by GiantCowFilms and was able to remove the newly installed DXF importer.  At least it appears to be the one deleted when I removed the _init_.py file.  I then went to the Addons menu in Blender and saw that there was only one "Import-Export: Export Autocad DXF Format (.dxf)" option in the list. It looks to be the one I used initially that had the running man icon and the explanation mark sign that indicated "Under Construction". It is version 8.1.3.  Can and should I replace it?

Comment: I would get rid of all of them then install the one you want

Answer (score 1):

The above answer does not address the case of 3rd-party addons. On Windows, new versions of Blender will install 3rd-party add-ons to the AppData folder under `[Username]/AppData/Roaming/Blender Foundation/Blender/[Version]/scripts/addons`. Delete the folder with the same name as your addon. Remember to also disable it (if you haven't already done so) in the `Add-ons` section of the preferences menu, or Blender will complain about that it can't find the addon on startup.