# How do I import a dxf?

Tags: import

I am a noob with blender. Please be as specific as possible. College students have been doing this for me, but I am unable to understand them.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26953/how-can-i-uninstall-an-add-on (specifically if your have additional dxf importers enabled... which might happen...)

Answer (score 16):

There are various dxf import / export plugins, but they are not enabled by default. One of these is specifically for Import (read carefully).

In the *User Preferences* window find the *Add-ons* tab.

[image]

Then when it's ticked, the `.dxf` import option becomes available in the File->Import menu

[image]