# How can I import Gerber DXF pattern into blender?

Tags: import

I have DXF files from Gerber which I want to import in Blender for 3D simulation. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In the info bar at the top left hand of the blender program try 'file', then 'import' the find AutoCAD DXF.

try it and keep me posted.

Comment: let me know if that option is availible, because if it is not, you might have to turn on a plugin to active this option.

Comment: Yup some else had the same issue, you can active this option though Add-ons found in the user preferences section. link to answer http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30788/how-do-i-import-a-dxf