# Looking for software to make an Interior 3d Rendering

Tags: rendering

I'm looking for a software program that can create a 3d rendering of an interior space. I have the floor plan (if it can make it from a floor plan, all the better, but not necessary), I just need a rendering of the space to make it look kick ass for a presentation! Is Blender the right software for me? I have some graphic design background, but not a ton and I'm worried this product might have too much of a learning curve for what I want to do.

Comment: Blender is powerful and flexible and thus requires learning and training.  I do not create renderings from Floor Plans so my knowledge is limited in your area.  A suggestion is to mention your timeline, is it days or months?  You may want to see the simpler Scratchup ... I mean Sketchup from the G company.  The G company finances some Blender development.  Lastly most questions here are from people who actively use Blender, not about deciding to use Blender.   All of Stack Exchange can put a focus on a topic and choose to mark other question as ... off topic.

Comment: A suggestion is to see video tutorials on Scratchup and Blender.  Blender tutorial series ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lY6KPrc4uMw&list=PLda3VoSoc_TR7X7wfblBGiRz-bvhKpGkS .  I am sure you can do a better web search than I can.

Comment: Yes you can do what you want using blender. Whether you want to take the time to learn it or not is up to you. For "kick ass look" you will need a high degree of proficiency (the same is true for any other software) Don't expect any magic pill or a magic menu with no effort kind solution from this or other software... If you are under a deadline consider getting help from someone that knows how to use the tools.

Comment: @Nancy if you're looking for something really simple you could try http://www.sweethome3d.com/it/  you can also export that in blender, later and render it there (see the bottom part of http://www.sweethome3d.com/it/userGuide.jsp)

Comment: you can get your 2d to 3d (rendered) interior here, all you need to do is submit a floorplan
http://3dify.archilogic.com/
(you can also download your model as a baked .blend file)

Comment: There is plenty of cutting-edge 3D Rendering software out in the world. V-ray is commonly used for rendering and 3Ds Max for modeling. Different software has it own edges judging from different aspects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to add a real-world testimony in addition to what is already stated in the comments.

Blender is perfectly capable (and quite good at it too) of doing realistic architectural renderings; I am an architect and happily use Blender for what you describe on a daily basis.

You can [import plans in DXF format](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30788/how-do-i-import-a-dxf) directly from a CAD drawing using the default shipped-in [DXF Importer addon](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/DXF_Importer).

As already mentioned before, there is a well-known steep learning curve compared to other software. It **will require effort** and time on your part to learn it, and will also require additional time to get proficient with it.

If this is a one-off thing, I am sad to say that Blender is probably not the software for you. The initial investment might just be too big for a single use and the difficulty too much to get you anywhere in a short time.

In that case, [Sketchup](https://www.sketchup.com/) or other "lighter" software might be a better option.

If you plan on doing this in the long run and want to invest some time into it, then it might be very rewarding further down the road to endeavor in the Blender road.

Comment: Thank you all so much for help!  I really appreciate it and it has helped me decide what to do.

Comment: If the answer helped you please consider upvoting it, and if it completely solved your problem mark it as accepted so it can be considered "closed"

Comment: Wasn't sure how to do what you asked, but I think I figured out how to accept it to close it, but not sure if I upvoted it or not (clicked on the up arrow).  Hopefully I've done both. Thank you!

Comment: Up arrow upvotes, and the check mark below it marks as accepted. We can never know who votes, but is is marked as accepted and that suffices. Thanks